# Как правильно создать активность с авторизацией (локальной, без сети)?

Tags: android, password

Добрый день. Как совсем начинающий разработчик, не могу разобраться с локальной авторизацией в приложении. С записью данных через SharedPreferences  разобрался, но хотелось бы как-то обезопасить данные. Подскажите способы пжлста..

Comment: От чего обезопасить?

Comment: сторонние приложения и так не имеют доступа к данным твоего, если ты сам не разрешишь. можешь шифровать :)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но я опасаюсь, что в случае утери телефона или работы вредоносных приложений - доступ будет весьма лёгок ко всем ресурсам. Чтобы было понятней, о чём я - я пишу для матери хранилку логинов и паролей к разным ресурсам , а то она всегда их либо  забывает, либо не помнит куда записала. Да и как начинающий разраб. хочется сделать всё по уму, чтобы за портфолио не краснеть.. Вот и хочу зашифровать грамотно данные, или спрятать..

Answer (score 0):

Можешь не хранить данные на телефоне, а хранить в бд MYSQL как пример!
[Читай](https://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/androidwithphp/login-and-registration-form-in-android/)